# Paper, Scissor, Rock game in Ruby. When an array changes data, it changes the data of another array (¿?)

Tags: ruby, arrays

This is my code:

```
class RockPaperScissors

   # Exceptions this class can raise:
  class NoSuchStrategyError < StandardError
  end

  def self.winner(player1, player2)
    if ((player1[1] == 'R') && (player2[1] == 'S') ||
        (player1[1] == 'S') && (player2[1] == 'P') ||
        (player1[1] == 'P') && (player2[1] == 'R'))
      return player1
    elsif ((player1[1] == 'R') && (player2[1] == 'P') ||
        (player1[1] == 'S') && (player2[1] == 'R') ||
        (player1[1] == 'P') && (player2[1] == 'S'))
      return player2
    elsif ((player1[1] == 'R') && (player2[1] == 'R') ||
        (player1[1] == 'S') && (player2[1] == 'S') ||
        (player1[1] == 'P') && (player2[1] == 'P'))
      return player1
    end

  end

  def self.tournament_winner(tournament)
    player1 = Array.new
    player2 = Array.new
    nextround = Array.new

    while tournament.length != 1 do

      tournament.each_with_index {|item, index|
        if (index%2!=0)
          player2[0] = item[0]
          player2[1] = item[1]
        elsif (index%2 ==0)
          player1[0] = item[0]
          player1[1] = item[1]
        else
          puts 'bananas'
        end

        if (index%2!=0)
          nextround[(index-1)/2] = winner(player1, player2)
        end
      }
      tournament=nextround
    end
    return tournament

  end
end



RockPaperScissors.tournament_winner([["num1", "R"], ["num2", "P"], ["num3", "P"], ["num4", "R"]])
```

Well, the last line is an execution launch. This code makes a tournament of rock, paper scissors. It takes as input an array of arrays with each character and its attack, and it has to return the array with the champion and its attack.

The tournament is num1 vs num2 (num2 wins), and num3 vs num4 (num3 wins). Then the final is Num2 vs Num3, and in this stablemate wins the first guy in the array (Num2).

It seems overcomplicated because the code has to work with any number of characters, as long as their number is base2 (2, 4, 8, 16 characters..., etc).

My problem is next (debug the code and you will see). When it changes the value of the array 'Player1' or 'Player2', it also changes the value in the array 'nextround', even if it is not in that line!

That is not suppose to happen!

By the way, I am learning Ruby so it may be a really stupid failure.

Comment: Ok, it is already resolved.

It seems that the array 'nextround' contained [player1, player2], or something like that.

Comment: The first argument of tournament_winner is `["num1", "R"]`.  Does that mean player 1 will always play "R"? If so, what happens if, at some point in the tournament, player 1 meets player 4, who also plays "R"?  If not, please clarify your explanation of the strategy used by each player.

Answer (score 0):

why does this need to be true?

> "It seems overcomplicated because the code has to work with any number of characters, as long as their number is base2 (2, 4, 8, 16 characters..., etc)."

Rather having player1 and player2 be arrays, I would rewrite them to be instances of a class Player. Then write methods in the Player class so you can call `player1.hand` and it returns `'S' || 'R' || 'P'`

that way you can store how many wins a player has on the player object,

things I'd look into learning more about

- case/when statements
- the special initialize method
- attrs_accessor (used for making data accessible across classes)
- modules

also i've seen it done and i may be wrong on this, but generally you don't put classes inside classes.